# Majority Voting statistical test

Tags: r, statistical-significance

What statistical test would be appropriate to test whether the number of votes of a winner is significant when there are more than 2 levels?

For the case of 2 levels I found [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49945/finding-the-test-statistic-for-a-majority-hypothesis). But is there an extension for more levels?

For example, given 3 candidates: A,B and C with number of votes:

A=59

B=45

C=53

I would like to test if A was really the winner or if it was just by chance with a given significance level. Preferably with an R implementation.

I found that a chi-squared test could be used but it just tells whether there was a significant difference between any of the groups but I want to test if the candidate with the highest number of votes is significantly better than the others.

I thought about comparing just the highest one with the second highest but I think that approach is not correct since I would be discarding information of the other candidates.

Comment: Ordinarily there is no concept of "significance" in the winner of an election: the winner is the person with the most votes, period. Thus, to understand this situation as you do, we need to hear from you concerning your *probability model* for the election outcome. Exactly how do you conceive of this election as occurring by chance?

Comment: Also with election you generally have the *whole population* that voted (some vote by not voting), so if you have data on whole population, then by definition each difference is statistically significant.

Comment: Specifically, those votes come from an ensemble of n trees (Random  Forest) and the candidates are the classes. My concern is that with a diffrent n the distribution of votes over classes changes. For two clases, if i get A=90 and B=10 votes then my certainty about which is the final class is high so my prediction will be 'A'. If A=51 and B=49 my certainty is low and in this case my prediction should be 'unknown'.

Answer (score 0):

I answered your question today in the comments section of [Finding the test statistic for a majority hypothesis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49945/finding-the-test-statistic-for-a-majority-hypothesis/623814#623814)

In a three or more candidates case, this can always be reduced to 2 choices, specifically:

You need to add this factor here: When A=59 , B=45 , C=53, reduce the vote to A and NOT A, in percent, and in this case it will be : A = 59/(59+45+53), and NOT A = (45+53)/(59+45+53) . Now that you have one candidate being tested, you can use the formula and answer I show in the stack exchange above.